# 302 status code after posting

Tags: php, post, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to figure out why I am getting this code. I can see my POST method on my developer tools but it has a 302 code found on it. It's not posting my data either to my table. Could the 302 code cause my data not to post?

I can see my data, but its not going to where I want it to go.

I have a switch case statement that changes on the $_GET key of view.

This is what I am getting back from developer tools

```
Request URL:http://www.myurl.com/roi/?view=ticket_submit
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

I have a switch case statement to look for different types of values in the key of view.

It's never getting to the case of ticket_view even though my tools tells me its there. So the question is, am I not posting my data correctly or is the 302 throwing it off or both?

Comment: 302 is usually tied into a `Location:` redirect, which a lot of browsers then do as a GET request, meaning the POST data is lost. However, many server-side post handlers also do post-redirect to prevent re-running a posted request if the user hits refresh.

Comment: So I would just get rid of the location redirect?

Comment: are you doing the 302 yourself? disable it and add some debugging to the post handler to see why it's not working.

Comment: Okay, let me try a few things.

Comment: please post the actual, full HTTP headers... you can edit the url etc, but it would be important to know which headers go with the request and which with the response

Comment: Are you referring to the request headers?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a server configuration issue. There are no redirects I am doing and it just throwing me this 302 response.

Answer (score 0):

The handler sitting at `/roi/?view=ticket_submit` is throwing the HTTP 302 status. You should also be getting a location the handler is trying to redirect the web-browser too..

I guess the redirection is not handled correctly at the server side.